# How to create a light effect inside a rectangle in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have tried to do this here http://wonderfl.net/c/9Kdv but what I want is not this

[alt text http://reboltutorial.com/images/flash-banner-trial.png](http://reboltutorial.com/images/flash-banner-trial.png)

but rather the equivalent of this. As I'm flash newbie I don't see how:

[image]
<sub>(source: [reboltutorial.com](http://reboltutorial.com/files/2010/05/create-free-banner.png))</sub>

action script 3 code below:

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.filters.*;

    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    public class FlashTest extends Sprite {
        public function FlashTest() {
            var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            mc.graphics.beginFill(0x400000);
            mc.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 278, 170,25,25);
            mc.graphics.endFill();
            mc.x = 80;
            mc.y = 60;
            addChild(mc);  

            //from tut http://blog.0tutor.com/post.aspx?id=116
            var filt:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter();  
            var filt_shadow:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter();              
            //here we add some properties to the two filters, the glow filter we give a color.   
             filt.color = 0xFF0000;  

             //and how much it should blur.   
             filt.blurX = 7;  
             filt.blurY = 7;  

             //then the dropshadow filter, also how much it should blur on the object.   
             filt_shadow.blurX = 4;  
             filt_shadow.blurY = 4;  

             //and finally an alpha, the alpha goes from 1 to 0, 1 being fully visible and 0 is transparent, then of cause .5 is just in between.   
             filt_shadow.alpha = .4;  


             mc.filters =  [filt,filt_shadow];

            var theTextField:TextField = new TextField();
            theTextField.border = false;
            theTextField.x = 30;
            theTextField.y = 50;
            theTextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            theTextField.text = "Experiment";

            var myformat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            myformat.color = 0xFFFFFF;
            myformat.size =24;
            myformat.align="center";                
            myformat.font = "Impact";

            theTextField.setTextFormat(myformat);   
            mc.addChild(theTextField);      

            var url:String = "//www.rebol.com/graphics/reb-logo.gif";
            var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

            var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
            ldr.load(urlReq);
            ldr.x=30;
            ldr.y=88;
            mc.addChild(ldr);


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this line:

```
mc.graphics.beginFill(0x400000);
```

you can use [beginGradientFill](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginGradientFill()) with the fillType set to [GradientType.RADIAL](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/GradientType.html#RADIAL). You would just need to adjust the focalPointRatio to make it offcenter. Check out the example in the docs for how to do this.

Comment: Hi thanks that seems what I should use, but it's not easy to know the parameters values. I have done something but am wandering a lot :)

Comment: There are quite a few examples out there on how to use beginGradientFill. The link above shows an example with parameters, and Google have even more help.